# C++ Array with variable sizes

Tags: c++

Is there a way to make an array in c++ where the size is determined by the user? Because you cannot use a constant variable that is determined by the user . . . help?

Comment: `std::vector` (preferably), `operator new` (less preferably)... did you use Google at all?

Comment: 4 downvotes is a bit too harsh for a question that is well formed and not offensive (wanting an array sized at realtime is not offensive, is it?)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with arrays. Use a `std::vector` instead. (Or if this is for a homework assignment, you might have to learn about dynamic memory management with `new[]` and `delete[]`.)